# Successful Jenkins Build marked as failed

Tags: maven, jenkins, build

Starting a few days ago, we've had problems with our Jenkins installation that handles the CI and release builds for a medium-sized enterprise project. One particularly annoying issue is the build server marking builds as "failed" (e-mail notification and everything) even though no failure reason at all is apparent from the build log.

Example output for one of our most recent failed builds:

```
[JENKINS] Recording test results
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- xml-maven-plugin:1.0:validate (default) @ <project name> ---
[JENKINS] Archiving disabled
[JENKINS] Archiving disabled
[JENKINS] Archiving disabled
[JENKINS] Archiving disabled
[JENKINS] Archiving disabled
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] <project name> (application) ................ SUCCESS [  4.408 s]
[INFO] <project name> commons .................. SUCCESS [ 52.580 s]
[INFO] <project name> Database Layer ........... SUCCESS [ 39.305 s]
[INFO] <project name> .......................... SUCCESS [07:57 min]
[INFO] <project name> .............................. SUCCESS [01:51 min]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 13:40 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-11-09T15:42:17+01:00
[JENKINS] Archiving disabled
[INFO] Final Memory: 72M/434M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
channel stopped
Finished: SUCCESS
```

The projects are hosted in an SVN repository and built using maven. Any idea on how I can analyze this issue further?

edit: In response to the question "how do we know it's broken": Jenkins marks the build with a red icon in the overview. We disabled email notification as recommended. unfortunately, this did nothing to change current behavior. Archiving is already disabled. I updated the build output to reflect the current configuration.

Any other ideas?

Comment: Where do you see this, cause this line `Finished: SUCCESS` says something different.

Comment: Indeed looks like build finished successfully, perhaps the issue is with your email trigger?

Comment: "Waiting for Jenkins to finish collecting data" usually means jenkins is in process of creating fingerprints to discover dependencies among your builds. Disable the fingerprinting and see if that helps. Also keep an eye on excessive heap consumption due to blocked thread.

Comment: Could you provide the full build log, which is helpful for others to analyze the issue.

Comment: I won't be able to provide the full build log as I'm working under an NDA, sorry. The build itself succeeds (and does so when run directly, i.e. not from within Jenkins). However, Jenkins marks the build red in the overview and sends out mails with the message "Build failed" which renders the tool pretty much useless for us. Thanks for the advice, I'll try disabling email trigger and fingerprinting and see if this helps.

Comment: It did not, unfortunately. I added the info to the description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to fix this myself, by going into the configuration of the failing build jobs, expanding the advanced options of the Maven Jenkins plugin and selecting the option "Run Headless". I do not have the slightest clue as to why this helps, but it does.

Comment: Weird - I'm seeing this issue intermittently with 1.609.3, just twice, both times with non-maven builds. The build.xml shows me SUCCESS but the build ball is RED in the UI. I've been running 1.609.3 for months and it just started happening this week, so I'm not sure what factors are involved that have the bug exhibiting only recently.

Comment: I'm using free style project and face the same error ... I can't find any solution for this error.

Comment: Having this issue with a custom pipeline.

Comment: run headless not fixed the issue, That issue is irritating..!, If anybody have other suggestions pl post